# Form action URL - Plus to space

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, xhtml, themes

I have a form in my wordpress theme. I want add a "plus" to space in url.

My source code:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="/search/" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" />
<input type="submit" class="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( '', 'themeO' ); ?>"  onclick="window.location.href=this.form.action + this.form.s.value;" />
</form>
```

my actual search url - keyword : "good job"

```
http://www.example.com/search/good job
```

I need this url:

```
http://www.example.com/search/good+job
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace()` to replace spaces with pluses:

```
window.location.href=this.form.action + this.form.s.value.replace(/\s+/g,"+");
```

Comment: window.location.href=this.form.action + this.form.s.value.replace(/\s/g,'+');  this is works thanks.

Comment: @mentoran If answer works, you can click the checkmark below vote count to make it entirely green (it is called "to accept an answer").